# QGIS field calculator interpolating over raster

Tags: gis, qgis

I want to add a z field to my shapefile. Z value is the elevation of the center of the basin. I wonder how should I acomplish that. x and y values of the centroids are in the table. I have the dem of the region.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert those xy coordinates to a point feature class and then you can use the 'Point sampling tool' plugin to assign the value of your basin raster/polygon to each point (similar to the 'Extract Values to Points' tool in ArcGIS).

Comment: I wondered if it is possible to do that with field calculator ?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the raster directly in Field Calculator. Create a new field and populate with:

```
raster_value('Raster', 1, make_point( x(centroid($geometry)), y(centroid($geometry))))
```

'Raster' is the raster layer, 1 is the band in the raster layer to use, and the make_point() function generates the centroid.